# What does render args mean?

Tags: magento2, shipping, code-analysis

In my shipping.html  I see this line of code

```
<render args="shippingMethodListTemplate"/>
```

Is this just saying "put the content of this template here" or is there something else going on?

EDIT:
if this is just calling this content how do I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open following class

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js

```
defaults: {
    template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping',
    shippingFormTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/form',
    shippingMethodListTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/shipping-method-list',
    shippingMethodItemTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/shipping-method-item'
},
```

**shippingMethodListTemplate** is html template.

Now in your case:

```
<render args="shippingMethodListTemplate"/>
```

This code render

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-list.html

template.

Comment: can you please  help me to solve this issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309955/checkout-page-error-in-magento-2