# Checkout page error in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

Checkout page error in Magento 2

Expected Result:

[image]

Actual Result:

In the frontend checkout page, it shows an error.

[image: 2]

**Source code in GitHub: https://github.com/sd2894/OrderAttributes**

how to define **shippingMethodListTemplate**  and **shippingFormTemplate** in js file how to override `shipping.js` in custom module in magento 2

Comment: Have you created the function that you've mentioned into html binding ?

Comment: i download a code from github and used please refer the code in  https://github.com/sd2894/OrderAttributes

Comment: have you deployed content ? and other steps to regenerate code ?

Comment: i deployed  a content

Comment: Which Magento 2 version?

Comment: magento 2.1.3 version

Comment: Thanks for sharing the module I think it's a great module for me. I have added the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update one file and it will work.

> app/code/Ecomteck/OrderCustomAttributes/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<li id="shipping" class="checkout-shipping-address" data-bind="fadeVisible: visible()">
    <each args="getRegion('before-shipping-address')" render="" />
    <div class="step-title" translate="'Shipping Address'" data-role="title" />
    <div id="checkout-step-shipping"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">

        <each if="!quoteIsVirtual" args="getRegion('customer-email')" render="" />
        <each args="getRegion('address-list')" render="" />
        <each args="getRegion('address-list-additional-addresses')" render="" />

        <!-- Address form pop up -->
        <!-- ko if: (!isFormInline) -->
        <button type="button"
                data-bind="click: showFormPopUp, visible: !isNewAddressAdded()"
                class="action action-show-popup">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'New Address'"></span></button>
        <div id="opc-new-shipping-address" data-bind="visible: isFormPopUpVisible()">
            <!-- ko template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/form' --><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <each args="getRegion('before-form')" render="" />

        <!-- Inline address form -->
        <!-- ko if: (isFormInline) -->
        <!-- ko template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/form' --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <each args="getRegion('after-form')" render="" />
    </div>
    <each args="getRegion('after-shipping-address')" render="" />
</li>

<!--Shipping method template-->
<li id="opc-shipping_method"
    class="checkout-shipping-method"
    data-bind="fadeVisible: visible(), blockLoader: isLoading"
    role="presentation">
    <each args="getRegion('before-shipping-method')" render="" />
    <div class="checkout-shipping-method">
        <div class="step-title"
             translate="'Shipping Methods'"
             data-role="title" />

        <each args="getRegion('before-shipping-method-form')" render="" />

        <div id="checkout-step-shipping_method"
             class="step-content"
             data-role="content"
             role="tabpanel"
             aria-hidden="false">
            <form id="co-shipping-method-form"
                  class="form methods-shipping"
                  if="rates().length"
                  submit="setShippingInformation"
                  novalidate="novalidate">

                <div id="checkout-shipping-method-load">
                    <table class="table-checkout-shipping-method">
                        <thead>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <th class="col col-method" data-bind="i18n: 'Select Method'"></th>
                            <th class="col col-price" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></th>
                            <th class="col col-method" data-bind="i18n: 'Method Title'"></th>
                            <th class="col col-carrier" data-bind="i18n: 'Carrier Title'"></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        <!--ko foreach: { data: rates(), as: 'method'}-->
                        <tr class="row" data-bind="click: $parent.selectShippingMethod">
                            <td class="col col-method">
                                <!-- ko ifnot: method.error_message -->
                                <!-- ko if: $parent.rates().length == 1 -->
                                <input class="radio"
                                       type="radio"
                                       data-bind="attr: {
                                                    checked: $parent.rates().length == 1,
                                                    'value' : method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code,
                                                    'id': 's_method_' + method.method_code,
                                                    'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code
                                                 }" />
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!--ko ifnot: ($parent.rates().length == 1)-->
                                <input type="radio"
                                       data-bind="
                                                value: method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code,
                                                checked: $parent.isSelected,
                                                attr: {
                                                    'id': 's_method_' + method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code,
                                                    'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code
                                                },
                                                click: $parent.selectShippingMethod"
                                       class="radio"/>
                                <!--/ko-->
                                <!-- /ko -->
                            </td>
                            <td class="col col-price">
                                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('price') -->
                                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- /ko -->
                            </td>

                            <td class="col col-method"
                                data-bind="text: method.method_title, attr: {'id': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code}"></td>

                            <td class="col col-carrier"
                                data-bind="text: method.carrier_title, attr: {'id': 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code}"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <!-- ko if:  method.error_message -->
                        <tr class="row row-error">
                            <td class="col col-error" colspan="4">
                                <div class="message error">
                                    <div data-bind="text: method.error_message"></div>
                                </div>
                                <span class="no-display">
                                    <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: {'value' : method.method_code, 'id': 's_method_' + method.method_code}"/>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- /ko -->

                        <!-- /ko -->
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div id="onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load">
                    <each args="getRegion('shippingAdditional')" render="" />
                </div>
                <div role="alert"
                     if="errorValidationMessage().length"
                     class="message notice">
                    <span text="errorValidationMessage()" />
                </div>
                <div class="actions-toolbar" id="shipping-method-buttons-container">
                    <div class="primary">
                        <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                            <span translate="'Next'" />
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="no-quotes-block"
                 ifnot="rates().length > 0"
                 translate="'Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time'" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <each args="getRegion('after-shipping-method')" render="" />
</li>
```

Comment: I cant  done a place order using that module can u please help me to solve this

Comment: Sure I was able to place the order in my local.

Comment: i had issue like that https://prnt.sc/s1171u   i checked in log  file but there is no any issue

Comment: check error log files.

Comment: i already checked a log file there is no information with today date

Comment: Show 404 error http://127.0.0.1/m2/magento/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information

Comment: Can u please help me solve this error https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310983/place-order-issue-in-payment-information-in-magento-2

Comment: Okay, I was busy in other works I got your updated module from that GitHub you have changed namespace?