# Place order issue in payment information in magento 2

Tags: magento2, place-order

Place order issue in payment information in magento 2

[image]

Code was shared in github : https://github.com/sd2894/OrderAttribute

Comment: please enable developer mode and check with

Comment: Still i m get a same issue. Can you please give your github username i will my share code @RakeshDonga

Comment: Any error in log ?

Comment: I suggest you to debug the place order function.

Comment: what other non core checkout related modules might you have installed, even if they are disabled? In my case an old version of the stripe module was one of the key problems

Comment: cant get you @iphigenie

Comment: ok when I had this error recently I looked at the headers and response in developer tools and looked at the trace it gave there. It pointed to savePaymentInfo in my case. It might point to another. In my case it was the old version of stripe causing a conflict.
What step is your problem at?

Comment: I do not understand, why you getting that error. it is working fine for me. can you share the scenario and have you check log files Magento logs and server logs? OR try after deleting files from a generated folder and run di compile

Comment: Which magento version  are you used @kunj

Comment: It's Magento Community 2.1.3

Comment: See this thread it will help. https://github.com/mcspronko/magento-2-payment-messages and https://www.maxpronko.com/how-to-show-payment-errors-on-the-checkout-payment-page-in-magento-2/

Comment: can you share system.log and exception.log

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you should have done some custom code on order creation event on your store. Or there might be any third party extension installed doing the same on your store.

This additional code is somewhere throwing an error that you can find in error logs under "/var/log" directory.

You can also turn on the error log by removing the comment from the line "**ini_set('display_errors', 1);**" in below located file:

> app/bootstrap.php

This will show you the exact error in specific file along with line no. These steps should help you to resolve your issue.

You are feel free to ask any further queries.

Happy to help.

Thanks,

Comment: Still i m get a same issue. Can you please give your  github  username i will my share code @Pratik Navapara

Answer (score 1):

try to check or debug in a custom module or third party module any set event after place order like

```
<event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="devi_checkout_submit_all_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\NewOrder"/>
    </event>
```

if set then disable event and hit below commands and then check order is placed or not

```
sudo rm -rf var/* generated/* pub/static/frontend/*
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento ca:cl
sudo php bin/magento ca:fl
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/(project name)/
```

so you could find what is the exact issue.